# Find the value of $x+y$ knowing that $x^3+y^3=9xy-27$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring, substitution

Find the value of $x+y$

where   $x^3+y^3=9xy-27.$

I tried using $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2+b^2−ab)$ and also $a^3+b^3=(a+b)^3−3ab(a+b)$

but couldn't find the answer. Please explain how do I solve these types of questions.

Answer given = 6

Comment: $x=y=3$ is a solution lol

Comment: I think you should post your question a little more clearly to avoid unnecessary misunderstanding, it's better to say find the value of ... where ... for some x and y

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's just consider real situation. Let $u=x+y$, $v=xy$, then $u^3-3uv=9v-27$, i.e., $(u+3)(u^2-3u+9-3v)=0$. So one case is $u=-3$, another is $u\neq -3$ and $v=\frac{1}{3}(u^2-3u+9)$. Since $x$, $y$ are both real, $u^2\ge 4v$, i.e., $(u-6)^2\le 0$, then $u=6$.

Comment: Beautiful solution! +1.

Comment: I voted +1 and I saw +2 before and then $0$, Someone voted -1.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg lol, thank u and that's all right

Comment: I upvote your solution which is clever but should be more detailed.

Comment: This is the way to go IMHO. Use elementary symmetric polynomials. Read about Newton (-Girard) identities to learn how to write higher power sums in terms of the elementary symmetric polynomials.

Comment: Can you explain the last sentence in more detail, please?

Comment: @lateralter $u^2\ge 4v=\frac{4}{3}(u^2-3u+9)$, then $u^2-12u+36\le 0$, i.e., $(u-6)^2\le 0$

Comment: $  u^2≥4v $ how we got this?

Comment: @lateralter this is just $(x+y)^2\ge 4xy$

Comment: Is this the general term to be in real?

Comment: @lateralter it's equivalent to $(x-y)^2\ge 0$, if $x-y$ is real, this clearly holds

Comment: @user360777 How you got $(u+3).(u^2 - 3u+9-3v)=0$?

Comment: @lateralter rewrite, $u^3+27=9v+3uv$, then both sides have factor $u+3$

Comment: @user360777 Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Use Euler's identity $$x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=\frac{1}{2}(x+y+z)\big( (x-y)^2+(x-z)^2+(y-z)^2\big)$$

Answer (score 3):

Let

$$\tag{1} f(x,y):=x^3+y^3-9xy+27=0$$

I don't agree with the unique answer $x+y=6$ to this problem. It should also include $x+y=-3$.

Here is why:

We are looking for constant(s) $k$ such that:

$$\tag{2}x+y=k.$$

Let us substitute $y=k-x$ in (1), yielding the equivalent problem : find $k$ and $x$ such that:

$$\tag{3} 3(k+3) x^2  - 3k(k+3)x    + (27+k^3)=0$$

But $27+k^3=3^3+k^3=(k+3)(k^2-3k+9)$; thus (3) is equivalent to;

$$\tag{4} (k+3)(3 x^2  - 3kx    + (k^2-3k+9))=0$$

Two consequences:

- either $k=-3$ which is one possibility for $k$ ; and **any** x is solution, thus any $(x,y)=(-x,-3-x)$ is a solution.
- or $x$ and $k$ are such that $x$ is a real root of quadratic equation

$$\tag{5} 3 x^2  - 3kx    + (k^2-3k+9)=0$$

whose discriminant: $\Delta=-3(k-6)^2$ is always negative but for the particular value $k=6$, in which case $x$ is equal to the double root of this equation, i.e. $x=\dfrac{1}{6}(3 \times 6+0)=3$; therefore, $y=k-x=6-3=3$.

Let us conclude:

> - either $x+y=-3$, and there is an infinity of solutions $\forall x, (x,y)=(x,-3-x)$.
> - or $x+y=6$, and there is a unique solution $(x_0,y_0)=(3,3).$

This is made very clear when we consider the "curve" of implicit function defined by (1), which is in two parts : a straight line with equation $x+y=-3$ representing the "general case" and an **isolated point** correponding to the particular solution $(x_0,y_0)=(3,3).$

**Remark:** Calling figure 1 a "curve" may look exaggerated. We must understand that it is a limit case of curves with equation $f(x,y)=z$ where $z$ is a real parameter; said otherwise of different level curves of the surface with equation $z=f(x,y)$ (see figure 2 for a representation of some of them). All are **cubic curves**. OIn the case $z=27$ (in red), thus with equation $x^3+y^3-9xy=0$, we have the **folium of Descartes** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folium_of_Descartes).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your solution is wrong! Try $x=y=3$.

Comment: I think it's from different points of view. He did't express clearly that we calculate $x+y$ for any or some $x$, $y$ such that $x^3+y^3=9xy-27$. If for 'any', there is no answer, and if for 'some', then $k=-3$ or $k=6$ in real situations.

Comment: @user360777  See my solution.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg yours is okay, actually my answer is the same as yours essentially

Comment: i know what you mean, but your interpretation is not totally accurate, cuz for $x=y=3$ (is a solution), $x+y\neq -3$. there's no such $k$ s.t. for any solution $x$, $y$, $x+y\equiv k$, but there does exist a $k$ in general meaning

Comment: @user360777 I agree with you, it is a question of definition. I have tried to show it with a first order logic presentation in a modified version of my answer. In fact, we are faced to a very particular cubic.

Answer (score 2):

If $x=y=3$ we have $x+y=6$.

Let $x\neq y$.
Thus,
$$x^3+y^3+27-9xy=(x+y+3)(x^2+y^2+9-xy-3x-3y),$$
which gives $x+y=-3$ because $x^2+y^2+9-xy-3x-3y\neq0$ for $x\neq y$.

Id est, the answer is $\{6,-3\}$.

Comment: @Jean Marie It was your conclude.  I fixed my post for you. See now, please.

Comment: @Jean Marie My last line is "Id est, the answer is $\{6,-3\}$" Why does it erroneous?

Comment: @Jean Marie See the given better. We need to find a value of $x+y$.

Comment: @Jean Marie I saw already. Your solution was wrong and my solution was true.

Comment: Do we agree on the graphical representation I have given, and the interpretation that goes with it : for the "general case", it is a $\exists k \ $ s.t. $ \ \forall x \exists y \ $ s.t. (1) is true, for the particular case it is a $\exists k \exists x \exists y$ s.t. (1) is true (as well understood in a previous remark by @user360777).

Comment: Even if consider that your solution as incomplete (you don't explain why $x^2+y^2+9-xy-3x-3y\neq0$ if $x \neq y$), I upvote it.

Comment: @Jean Marie I thought that it's obvious. $x^2+y^2+9-xy-3x-3y=\frac{1}{2}((x-y)^2+(x-3)^2+(y-3)^2)>0$.

Comment: Obvious, not to everybody !!! Not to me in particular...